# Change of number with addition of "seems to" e.g. "this MEANS" vs. "this seems to MEAN"

Tags: grammatical-number

The "number" (not sure what the appropriate term is; plurality?) of the verb matches the subject, so we say

`This means.` or `These mean.`

But why does the former change to singular when you add "seems to", as in:

`This seems to mean.` ?

Comment: Are you asking why "mean" in "seems to mean" doesn't have an "s"?

Comment: @KarlG yes i am.

Comment: It's the third person singular form of the verb. Compare with "John runs quickly"; "Jane walks slowly" and "Jimmy seems to be asleep". "This" is working as the third person singular so the verb takes an 's' but "These" is working as the third person plural so the verb has no 's'. Compare with "John and Jane seem to be awake".

Comment: "mean" in "This seems to mean" is an infinitive/plain form, not a plural form. A hint is the preceding "to", which is often used before an infinitive in English. Compare "This is...", "These are..." and "This seems to be..."

Comment: Thanks @sumelic that's very helpful, I considered it as `this seems-to mean` instead of `this seems to-mean`.

Comment: @BoldBen you are completely missing the point of the question, especially as was already clarified by KarlG...